# Can I use sublime Text build system to execute manage.py commands in a docker container?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, docker, sublimetext3

I'm writing unit tests for a Django App.  I'm using sublime text.  My app is set up to run in a docker container.  To run the tests currently I have to go into the docker container `sudo docker exec -it {containerID} /bin/bash` and then run `python manage.py test polls`.

Is there some way to do this from sublime text's build system?

I know I could set up the whole app to run out side the container then just command-B to build and run locally, but I want to run in the container.

Answer (score 0):

I created a build system with the following:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "docker-compose exec -T web sh -c 'python manage.py test polls'"
}
```

That runs the tests.  There's probably a way to get the app name and substitute it for polls, but for now this seems to work.